# Looking for the source code of the new Google Calendar Time and Date Picker Widgets

Tags: android, widget, google-calendar-api

I would like to use the brand new Date Picker and Time Picker that is now part of the new official Google Calendar App.

http://googlesystem.blogspot.de/2013/05/new-google-calendar-controls-for-android.html

All I found so far is this source code on grepcode but I can't find the widgets or fragments or activities there.

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/

Is that already public or is there something similar out there?

Comment: I do not believe it is in the source code as 4.2.2 came out before the new calendar update I believe. You will probably have to wait for 4.3 source to find it. in the mean time you can use this library https://github.com/biboune/datetimepicker

Answer (score 6):

I think the code you are looking for can be found here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/master/src/com/android/datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

There is some pretty directly usable source code snippets in this Android Developer Pages:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

I used it as-is and all works just fine.

Also, reference these:
DatePickerDialog
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html
TimePickerDialog
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html
DialogFragment
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html